# Get to get/set Input control values created in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, user-controls, controls

I have a number of Input (textbox) controls that are created in the codebehind as part of a dynamic RadiobuttonList control (so that a textbox is next to a radiobutton):

```
 RadioButtonList radioOption = new RadioButtonList();

 radiobuttonlist.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt1.Rows[i][9].ToString() + " <input id=\"" + name + "\" runat=\"server\" type=\"text\" value=\"Enter text\" />")
```

My question is, how do I access the input text in order to set or get it's value?

There are in total around 10 different input controls created as part of a loop.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Are you creating child control or adding an input text box as a item in the RadioButtonList collection.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use the FindControl method. Based on what your id is, you can iterate through them and find the control - and then cast it to the particular control that it is.

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)Page.FindControl(id);
```

Then you can set and get on it:

```
textBox.text = "text";
string text = textBox.text;
```

EDIT: You may also need to add the runat="server" tag to the dynamically created text box in order to access it from the server side.